# What's "that strength"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

From [NPR](http://www.npr.org/templates/transcript/transcript.php?storyId=276484952)

> ... And tho’
> We are not now ***that strength*** which in old days
> Moved earth and heaven, that which we are, we are:
> One equal temper of heroic hearts,
> Made weak by time and fate, but strong in will
> To strive, to seek, to find and not to yield.

If I extract the main part of the sentence, it would be:

> We are not strength.

Which is very odd. Because *strength* is only a noun to describe the physical power of a man, not the man himself. I know "that" can be used to describe how big, small, etc. I guess it could be used in this way here. So should the word *strength* be replace with *strong*? Just as follows:

> And though we are not now that ***strong*** which in old days moved earth and heaven, that which we are, we are: One equal temper of heroic hearts, made weak by time and fate, but strong in will to strive, to seek, to find and not to yield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is 19th-century poetry, and Tennyson was a little given to archaisms. A *strength* is an obsolete term for a company of troops<sup>†</sup>, and Ulysses is addressing “my mariners”, the men whom he led to Troy and who passed many dangers with him on the return voyage. So he's saying “We aren’t that band of young warriors we once were, men capable of anything; but what we still *are* is heroically willing to try.”

Tennyson appears to have forgotten that Ulysses returned to Ithaca alone, all his companions having perished along the way.

---

<sup>†</sup> See [OED 1](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdicpt109murruoft#page/1106/mode/2up), 11.b.

Answer (score 2):

I think the *strength* there is uncountable noun and used to refer *natural force*. On the other hand, you are using *strong* as an adjective.

> We are not [the strength that moved earth and heaven] - reading this way may make sense.